# Save Procedure in Triggers and Order of Execution?

Tags: apex, trigger, order-of-execution

it is being written in

> Triggers and Order of Execution: that record goes through save procedure

[image]

Does it mean starting from the very first step or when the record got save to the database, point number 7 in this order. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It starts at step 1, from the very beginning, including validation rules, before triggers, and before flows. This update may be recursive yet again if any of those records also cause more updates.

Comment: thanks for the clarification @sfdcfox. Not sure why they are doing it in the first place as the recession is the worst thing that happens in the trigger execution. Also, one for query, do we have any flag which says updated from another source/process in SF such as Process builder/flows?

Comment: @Rohit This recursion allows validation at the parent level (e.g. not allow more than three products on an opportunity) as well as to update other data correctly. And no, we can't specifically tell if an update is recursive except in Apex, where we can set static variables.